# Confusion about $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}{(1+2+...+n)}$

Tags: calculus, summation

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}{(1+2+ ... +n)}$

I came across this example and it seems to be trivial. However, I am not particularly sure what it is going to equal if $n$ goes not to $\infty$, but to $n=2$, for example.

Could somebody explain what the sum equals if the upper limit of the sum is $2$ instead of $\infty$?

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: Are you asking what the value of $$\sum_{n=1}^{2} (1+2+\cdots+n)$$ is?

Comment: @Antonio Vargas Yes.

Comment: It would simply be 1+(1+2) = 4.

Comment: You seem fundamentally confused about the notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the first four partial sums.
You can perform the addition if you like;
what I have done here is merely to show how to interpret the notation.
There are two parts to this: 
how do we interpret $(1+2+ \ldots +n)$ for various values of $n$,
and what does it mean to take a summation over these values of $n$.

\begin{align}
\sum _{n=1}^{1}(1+2+ \ldots +n) &= (1). \\
\sum _{n=1}^{2}(1+2+ \ldots +n) &= (1) + (1 + 2). \\
\sum _{n=1}^{3}(1+2+ \ldots +n) &= (1) + (1 + 2) + (1 + 2 + 3). \\
\sum _{n=1}^{4}(1+2+ \ldots +n) &= (1) + (1 + 2) + (1 + 2 + 3) + (1+2+3+4).
\end{align}

I hope the pattern is evident from these examples.

Comment: Note that another, less confusing way of writing these would be e.g. $\sum_{n=1}^4(\sum_{i=1}^n i)$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Indeed, your notation is what I would use if I wanted to write the original formula myself. Of course either notation will result in the same partial sums.

Comment: @David K. Your example was helpful. Thank you.